# How to execute iisreset as different user?

Tags: asp.net, shell, vbscript, visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to do an iisreset on a webserver after clicking on the save button of one of the screen in lightswitch application. I could achive that with below code. Now I wanted to have the iisreset command done with different user not the logged on user.

How can I execute iisreset with a specific set of user credentials?

Really appreciate your help on finding a solution.

```
dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application");
shell.ShellExecute(iisreset.exe, "/noforce", "", "", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that how to achieve this with just vbscript, but you can install utility like [PsService](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx) & then restart the iisreset service where you can specify the username and password of user by which you have to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the runas command to launch it under a different user credentials.  A full vbscript example is here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/04/28/how-can-i-use-the-runas-command-to-run-a-script-under-alternate-user-credentials.aspx